# Maven assembly plugin with unicode characters

Tags: maven, unicode, maven-assembly-plugin

I have an external groovy script that i need to include in a zip file by means of the maven assembly plugin.

I can't just compile it, it needs to be in text-form.
The problem i am facing is that the script contains æ ø å characters, and that is causing some problems.
The script itself runs file from its place in the maven project, but when i package it with the maven assembly plugin, and then unzip it, its non ascii characters are corrupted. The script also runs fine if i use 7zip or the like to zip and unzip it, no corruption happens.

How can i tell the maven assembly plugin to conserve my special characters? I would really hate to have to make a lot of changes to the code in order to convert it to a maven project.

Here is a part of my pom

```
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/archive.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id> 
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

and my Descriptor

```
<id>archive</id>
  <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>    
...
    <fileSet>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
        <directory>src/main/groovy</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>BusinessServiceMock.groovy</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, after 3 hours of deep searching. I found another alternative of using `maven-antrun-plugin` instead of `maven-assembly-plugin` because it simply does not propose encoding for file name inside zip archive.

Here is my solution:

1.Firstly, to ensure that file names are in `UTF-8` encoding for example, I copy my ressource to project build repository and force input and output encoding.

2.Then i create my `zip` by adding the copied target directory.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <tasks>
                    <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/target"
                          includeemptydirs="true"
                          encoding="${project.build.sourceEncoding}"
                          outputencoding="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">
                        <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/resource">
                            <include name="**/*" />
                        </fileset>
                    </copy>
                    <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.zip"
                         encoding="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">
                        <zipfileset dir="${project.build.directory}/target" includes="**" />
                    </zip>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

To ensure that the encoding is ok you can use `maven-enforcer-plugin` to check subfolder and files encoding.